# Create a system process (ProcessBuilder) reattachable after main process quit

Tags: java, shell, process

I'm searching for a method to create a `Process` that keeps running after the main process of my application quit (it already do that) and that i can *re-get* in another instance of my application (after first instance exit).
I mean a thing like the screens in linux shells but for a java `Process`.
I don't know if that's possible...

Comment: what do you mean reget? What actions will be done on the child process after you get it in another instance of your application?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. You'll have to do regular inter-process communication.

Comment: Then can I create a non-child process controlled by my application?

Comment: To answer @KernelMode I need to control another java app instance inside that `Process` (execute commands and get the output)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can't get a `Process` object for existing processes, nor for processes that aren't children of your process.

`screen` works by never actually exiting. When you detach from a `screen` session it continues running in the background, maintaining control over the processes started inside of it. Re-attaching to a session makes it visible again, but it was really running the whole time.

Comment: But there's something screens-like for java?